# Format a posix time with just 3 digits in fractional seconds

Tags: c++, boost, time, datetime-format, time-format

What's the equivalent of `microsec_clock` for milliseconds in the following code?

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime date_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    const std::string str_time = boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(date_time);
    std::cout << str_time << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> output: 2015-Jan-25 16:26:14.932738

I need the following output:

> output: 2015-Jan-25 16:26:14.932

Comment: Just use some other function to format the string in any format you would like (one where you could limit the number of characters being written)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'd prefer not to do extra string manipulations here and get the desired value directly.

Comment: And if that's not possible? And wht do you think `to_simple_string` does? Somewhere a call to `strftime` is probably done, why not do it yourself so you can control the format precisely?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right. That should be the best way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this seems a strange omission from the library.

Then again, it doesn't look that `strftime` has the goods: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime

So, what would it take to patch the `time_facet` implementation to get this? Here's the [patch](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9872506/) against boost 1.57's `boost::date_time::time_facet.hpp` ([applied](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74d85a8591778995)).

```
1d0
< 
39a39
>       static const char_type fractional_seconds_3digits[3];              // 3
72a73,76
>   time_formats<CharT>::fractional_seconds_3digits[3] = {'%','3'};
> 
>   template <class CharT>
>   const typename time_formats<CharT>::char_type
215a220
>     static const char_type* fractional_seconds_3digits;               // %3
397a403,411
>       if (local_format.find(fractional_seconds_3digits) != string_type::npos) {
>         // replace %3 with nnn
>         if (frac_str.empty()) {
>           frac_str = fractional_seconds_as_3digit_string(time_arg.time_of_day(), false);
>         }
>         boost::algorithm::replace_all(local_format,
>                                       fractional_seconds_3digits,
>                                       frac_str);
>       }
506a521,529
>       if (format.find(fractional_seconds_3digits) != string_type::npos) {
>         // replace %3 with nnn
>         if (frac_str.empty()) {
>           frac_str = fractional_seconds_as_3digit_string(time_dur_arg, false);
>         }
>         boost::algorithm::replace_all(format,
>                                       fractional_seconds_3digits,
>                                       frac_str);
>       }
550a574,592
>     fractional_seconds_as_3digit_string(const time_duration_type& time_arg,
>                                  bool null_when_zero)
>     {
>       typename time_duration_type::fractional_seconds_type frac_sec =
>         time_arg.fractional_seconds();
> 
>       for (auto n = time_arg.num_fractional_digits(); n>3; --n)
>           frac_sec /= 10;
> 
>       if (null_when_zero && (frac_sec == 0)) {
>         return string_type();
>       }
> 
>       //make sure there is no sign
>       return integral_as_string(date_time::absolute_value(frac_sec), 3);
>     }
> 
>     static
>     string_type
599a642,645
> 
>   template <class time_type, class CharT, class OutItrT>
>   const typename time_facet<time_type, CharT, OutItrT>::char_type*
>   time_facet<time_type, CharT, OutItrT>::fractional_seconds_3digits = time_formats<CharT>::fractional_seconds_3digits;
```

Now you can just use Boost DateTime's `time_facet` for `ptime`s:

```
#include "time_facet.hpp"
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime const date_time = microsec_clock::local_time();

    std::cout << date_time << std::endl;

    auto facet = new time_facet("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z");
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
    std::cout << date_time << std::endl;

    facet = new time_facet("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S.%3 %z");
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
    std::cout << date_time << std::endl;
}
```

Which prints

```
2015-Jan-25 22:32:30.392108
2015-Jan-25 22:32:30.392108
2015-Jan-25 22:32:30.392
```

Now this is a rough patch, just to show what you'd need to get done iff you were to add this. The relevant improvements would seem to be:

- support a format string that allows different numbers of digits in the fractional seconds
- use proper rounding (instead of truncating, what happens now)

I hope this sample helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to print the string that is somewhat easier than patching the Boost library (!!). The key idea is to notice that `boost::posix_time::to_simple_string()` does not print the fractional part if it is precisely zero. So set the fractional part to zero, use `to_simple_string()`, then manually print the milliseconds yourself.

This leads to the next question: how do you strip the fractional part out of a boost `ptime`? The easiest way I have found (not necessary the easiest way that exists!) is to go via a `time_duration` using some absolute reference point. I have chosen 1970-01-01 for tradition's sake, but it doesn't matter what time point you choose (so long as it does not have a fractional seconds part!).

```
std::string time_with_milli(boost::posix_time::ptime time)
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    static const ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1900, 1, 1));  // Can be any date

    boost::posix_time::time_duration relative_time = time - epoch;
    boost::posix_time::ptime date_time_seconds_only = 
        epoch + boost::posix_time::seconds(relative_time.total_seconds());
    uint64_t milliseconds = relative_time.total_milliseconds() % 1000;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << to_simple_string(date_time_seconds_only) << '.' 
       << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << milliseconds;
    return ss.str();
}
```

This works equally well with `to_simple_string()`, `to_iso_string()` and `to_iso_extended_string()`, even though [the documentation for them](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_to_string) claims that only `to_simple_string()` omits the fractional part if it is zero.