# boost: time_facet milliseconds without dot

Tags: c++, boost

I need to create a timestamp with boost in the format:
YYYYmmDDhhMMssFFFF (with F = Milliseconds).
I use

```
facet->format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%F");
```

but the output includes always a dot between seconds and milliseconds. This is the output:
"20150202140830.779716"

Is there a better way to achieve my format than to replace the dot and cut the last two digits by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're interested, I implemented a custom facet the other day here: [Format a posix time with just 3 digits in fractional seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136660/format-a-posix-time-with-just-3-digits-in-fractional-seconds/28141927?s=1|0.0000#28141927)

You could use the same approach here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a588b6f6fe800986)</kbd>**

```
#include "time_facet.hpp"
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime const date_time = microsec_clock::local_time();

    std::cout << date_time << std::endl;

    auto facet = new time_facet("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S%4 %z");
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
    std::cout << date_time << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
2015-Feb-02 22:01:00.926982
2015-Feb-02 22:01:009269
```

Comment: Fixed my answer. I missed the fact that you wanted 4 digits, initially