# Can boost::posix_time::time_input_facet handle non-standard fractional second separators?

Tags: c++, boost

I am attempting to parse datetimes from text files. The timestamps have microsecond precision, but due to historical reasons beyond my control, they were created using a colon instead of a dot to separate the fractional seconds portion, e.g.:

```
2015/05/05 03:10:43:537408
```

instead of

```
2015/05/05 03:10:43.537408
```

I am able to parse these timestamps without preserving the fractional seconds using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
namespace bt = boost::posix_time;

const std::string inputString = "2015/05/05 03:10:43:537408";
const std::string inputFormat = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S%F";

bt::time_input_facet * facet = new bt::time_input_facet(inputFormat);
const std::locale loc(std::locale::classic(), facet);

std::istringstream iss(inputString);
iss.imbue(loc);
boost::posix_time::ptime pt;
iss >> pt;
```

As you might guess, using the lowercase-f fractional second formatter causes the parse to fail (pt remains not-a-date-time). Also, inserting a colon in the format string doesn't help:

```
const std::string inputFormat = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%F";
```

Boost seems to infer the dot separator.

Aside from explicitly checking for the colon separator and handling it differently, does anyone know if its possible to parse this non-standard time format using the boost library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no builtin way.

The time_facet get functions presume `'.'` as seperator:

```
    case 'f':
      {
        // check for decimal, check SV if missing
        if(*sitr == '.') {
          ++sitr;
          parse_frac_type(sitr, stream_end, frac);
          // sitr will point to next expected char after this parsing
          // is complete so no need to advance it
          use_current_char = true;
        }
        else {
          return check_special_value(sitr, stream_end, t, c);
        }
        break;
      }
    case 'F':
      {
        // check for decimal, skip if missing
        if(*sitr == '.') {
          ++sitr;
          parse_frac_type(sitr, stream_end, frac);
          // sitr will point to next expected char after this parsing
          // is complete so no need to advance it
          use_current_char = true;
        }
        else {
          // nothing was parsed so we don't want to advance sitr
          use_current_char = true;
        }
        break;
      }
```

You could modify the implementation (see e.g. [Format a posix time with just 3 digits in fractional seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136660/format-a-posix-time-with-just-3-digits-in-fractional-seconds/28141927)) or subclass and override the relevant member functions.

It's going to be a bit annoying regardless because the class wasn't designed for inheritance.

I'd personally think of a format string to indicate *just* fractional settings *without* any separator, so you can indeed include `:` inside the format specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you reimplement the "time_input_facet" class from "boost/data_time/time_facet.hpp" header and comment the following lines, you can solve your problem:

```
case 'f':
{
    // check for decimal, check SV if missing
    //if (*sitr == '.') {
        //++sitr;
        parse_frac_type(sitr, stream_end, frac);
        // sitr will point to next expected char after this parsing
        // is complete so no need to advance it
        use_current_char = true;
    //}
    //else {
    //    return check_special_value(sitr, stream_end, t, c);
    //}
    break;
}
case 'F':
{
    // check for decimal, skip if missing
    //if (*sitr == '.') {
        //++sitr;
        parse_frac_type(sitr, stream_end, frac);
        // sitr will point to next expected char after this parsing
        // is complete so no need to advance it
        use_current_char = true;
    //}
    //else {
    //    // nothing was parsed so we don't want to advance sitr
    //    use_current_char = true;
    //}
    break;
}
```